# Ng-repeat in view not updating except when fetching entire array from database

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

The issue of angular `ng-repeat` not updating correctly seems pretty common and there are already a number of threads on the issue. However for me it works in some cases and some other not which is very wierd and none of the other solutions on SO make it work..

So i have the following html:

```
<div ng-init="vm.loadItems()" ng-controller="itemController as vm">
 <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items>
  {{item.name}}
 </div>
 <form ng-submit="vm.submitItem()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.item.name">
 <button>Create new</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('itemController',function($scope, itemsService){

 vm.items = [];
 vm.item = { name : "" };

 vm.loadItems = function(){
  itemsService
   .getAll()
   .then(function(response){
    vm.items = response.data;
   });
 }

 vm.submitItem = function(){
  itemsService
   .createNew(vm.item)
   .then(function(response){
    var newItems = vm.items;
    newItems.push(response.data);
    vm.items = newItems;
    console.log(vm.items)
   });
 }
});
```

The service `itemsService` different methods used are `getAll()` which returns all items in the db using a `GET` request, and `createNew()` which creates a new item in the db using a `POST` request and then returns the created item.

When the page is loaded the items are correctly updated with `vm.loadItems()` but when i push the new item in `vm.submitItem()` the view doesn't change. I can fix this by instead using

```
vm.submitItem = function(){
 itemsService
  .createNew(vm.item)
  .then(function(){
    vm.loadItems();
  });
}
```

But this creates a very unnessecary second request to the backend.
I have tried using `$scope.$apply()` but get the error `$digest already in progress`. Using

```
$timeout(function(){
 vm.items = newItems;
});
```

doesn't work either.

Any ideas how to fix this greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't posted the code of the service, which might be the problem. You alsohaven't added any error callback, to identify if the promise returned by the promise was resolved or rejected.

Comment: The createNew method has no parameter (From the HTML I see the ng-model but the value isn't used).I think the POST is with empty body and it fails.Either you're creating empty values and inspect the page to see the empty divs.

Comment: Just forgot that when creating the post, i can see in the console.log that items are added to the array correctly. However the view is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is me at the rescue! :)

Your problem is that you are breaking the reference between ng-repeat and vm.items when you assign a new object. So the solution to your problem would be to change the function of the ".then" method when you created a new item. Take a look! :)

```
vm.submitItem = function(){
  itemsService
  .createNew(vm.item)
  .then(function(response){
    vm.items.push(response.data);
    console.log(vm.items);
  });
}
```

Less lines and your problem solved! ^^